# Why my cron jobs does not run this php file

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I have to run this php file `voteDay.php` via cron jobs.

```
<?php
require_once '../phpWorks/key.php';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO mail ( consignor, recipient, mail ) VALUES (?, ?, ? )');
$stmt->execute( array( "dictionary", "gun girl", "cron jobs is working" ) );
print_r( $stmt->errorInfo() );
?>
```

It basically puts a mail into an account. I already tested the file. it works great however my cron  jobs does not run it. Heres my cron job command

```
*/15  *  *  * *  /opt/php56/bin/php /home/kai/public_html/entryWorks/voteDay.php
```

I get this command from my host's knowledgebase. so it should have been work. Whats wrong?

Comment: Can you see your cron logs? Are you sure the path is correct? Also, be careful putting php scripts like this one in the public folder, bots will hit them and they will get executed without your control.

Comment: where can i store them except public?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the path. Try changing the include in this way:

```
require_once '/home/kai/public_html/phpWorks/key.php';
```

Is better to use absolute paths when you call the script from different places